Kubernetes stuck in CrashLoopBackOff when I try to use multus
I have a master node and a worker node in two virtual machines, one virtual machine(Ubuntu) is master node and the other one(also Ubuntu) is the worker node.
After installing Multus CNI using the following command(I am following github tutorial):
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/master/deployments/multus-daemonset-thick.yml

Kubernetes stuck in CrashLoopBackOff event and I don't know how to solve it.
enter image description here
I've also installed Flannel before installing multus CNI from the github flannel repo and I haven't had any problem.
I've also used thin multus plugin and I have the same problem.
Kubernetes version: 1.29.3
Host OS: Ubuntu
CNI and version: Multus(4.0 release)

The image didn't show up, also, do a kubectl describe pod foo for the crashlooping pod, which will give you a hunt in the kubernetes events for the pod in question.
